# Counting with variable/unknown values XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, foreach, count

I am very new to XSLT and I am trying to create a CSV of the number of publications each professor has had each year, Each entry is a different publication denoted by 
 `dm:INTELLCONT` and each year is denoted by `dm:DTY_PUB` I am having trouble figuring out how to do this properly if I do not hard code the year, I want to do this in a loop for every year they've published something. My Current XML file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2017-10-16">
    <INTELLCONT id="151370213376" dmd:originalSource="MANAGE_DATA" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T11:41:47" dmd:startDate="2016-04-15" dmd:endDate="2016-04-15">
        <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
        <CONTYPE>Abstract</CONTYPE>
        <CONTYPEOTHER/>
        <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
        <TITLE>Sample Title</TITLE>
        <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
        <DTM_PUB>April (2nd Quarter/Spring)</DTM_PUB>
        <DTD_PUB>15</DTD_PUB>
        <DTY_PUB>2016</DTY_PUB>
        <PUB_START>2016-04-15</PUB_START>
        <PUB_END>2016-04-15</PUB_END>
   <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
    </INTELLCONT>
        <INTELLCONT id="151368284160" dmd:originalSource="MANAGE_DATA" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T10:44:48" dmd:startDate="2017-01-01" dmd:endDate="2017-12-31">
            <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
            <CONTYPE>Journal Article</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Sample Title</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368284163">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>FN</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>LN</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368284161">
                <FACULTY_NAME>1898739</FACULTY_NAME>
                <FNAME>FN</FNAME>
                <MNAME>MN</MNAME>
                <LNAME>LN</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>Public Health</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>14</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE>3</ISSUE>
            <PAGENUM>265</PAGENUM>
            <DTY_PUB>2017</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2017-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2017-12-31</PUB_END>
    <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
         <INTELLCONT id="151368284160" dmd:originalSource="MANAGE_DATA" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T10:44:48" dmd:startDate="2017-01-01" dmd:endDate="2017-12-31">
            <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
            <CONTYPE>Journal Article</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Sample Title</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368284163">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>FN</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>LN</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>Public Health</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>14</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE>3</ISSUE>
            <PAGENUM>265</PAGENUM>
            <DTY_PUB>2017</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2017-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2017-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
</Data>
```

My current XSL File is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dm="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"
 xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
 xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
 xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
 xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs">
 
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
 <!-- xmlns:dm is the xmlns attribute in Data.-->
 
 <!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in -->
 <xsl:variable name="fieldArray">
  <field>Journal Articles</field>
  <field>Books</field>
  <field>Book Chapters</field>
  <field>Conference Proceeedings</field>
  <field>Others</field>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*" />
 
 <xsl:key name="Year-Published" match="dm:INTELLCONT" use="dm:DTY_PUB"/>
 <xsl:template match="/dm:Data">
  <!--key("Year-Published", '2017')-->
  <!--<xsl:text>Journal Articles</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
  <xsl:text>Books</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
  <xsl:text>Book Chapters</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
  <xsl:text>Conference Proceedings</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
  <xsl:text>Others</xsl:text>
  -->
  
  
  <xsl:text>Year,</xsl:text>
  <!-- tabulating Years as columns -->
  <xsl:for-each select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Year-Published', dm:DTY_PUB)[1])]">
   <xsl:sort select="(dm:DTY_PUB)" order="ascending"/> 
   <xsl:value-of select="(dm:DTY_PUB)"/> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each> 
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  
  
  
  <!-- Tabulating Published Papers  Per Year-->
  <xsl:for-each select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Year-Published', dm:DTY_PUB)[1])]">
   <xsl:sort select="(dm:DTY_PUB)" order="ascending"/> 
   <xsl:value-of select="count(dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Journal Article'][dm:STATUS='Published'][dm:DTY_PUB=key('Year-Published', dm:DTY_PUB)[1])][dm:USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR!='No'])"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
  </xsl:for-each> 
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  
  
  
  
  
  <!-- output newline -->
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see the part where I am trying to count each publication per year has the comment   **Tabulating Published Papers  Per Year**

I want to loop through every year they published and count how many publications exist that year, any help would be very very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mastered the basic idea of XSLT 1.0 Muenchian Grouping, which is the hard part, and then you've slipped up on a simple issue of context. Here:

```
<xsl:for-each select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[...]">
    <xsl:sort select="(dm:DTY_PUB)" order="ascending"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="count(dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[..]/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

that can't make sense because within the for-each, the context item is an INTELLICONT element, and you're trying to select downwards to a dn:RECORD.

In Muenchian grouping where you want to count the size of the group, the logical structure is

```
<xsl:for-each select="one item with each key value">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(all items with the same key value)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

so I would expect to see `count(key(....))`.

Are you sure you can't use XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:for-each-group` for this? It makes life so much easier...

Comment: I was told specifically I wasnt allowed to use version 2. I wish I was. Thank you for this I will give it a try

Comment: If only the people who made those decisions knew what they were costing in lost productivity...